# How to change all text in one rich text box to a specific color? (c#)

Tags: c#, colors, richtextbox

I have been trying to find how to change a rich text box into ONE color specifically, not multiple colors in one.  Google has been no help, because it assumes I am looking for multiple lines of random colors.  I saw nothing here, but I'm sure there is something on here, but I have yet to figure out how to ask the question properly I guess. So I ask it here. How do I do it? My code only displayed the color name in the rich text box, and changed the color of the start button which is not at all what I want. The eventual idea will be that everything that is typed that is the same, will be of that color. I figured this would be the simplest way of accomplishing that.

This is what I typed:

```
  if(TypeHere.Text == DisplayText.Text)
  {
  DisplayText.Text = Convert.ToString(ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
  }
```

That obviously didn't work like I thought it would. I'm sure I'm either missing a crucial step, or not entirely understanding how colors work on WF.  I placed this in the TypeHere. The output of this in DisplayText is:

```
 Color[Blue]
```

It wouldn't let me just set DisplayText to equal the color implicitly. I realize why it displays the name in the textbox, but I don't understand why it changes the color of the text in my button? I've tried it both as a method, and a couple of lines of code in the text box.  So it's obviously not where I place the code, but something else.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Set the `ForeColor` property of the `RichTextBox`. This will change the font color in the `RichTextBox`.

```
 richTextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```